# Faster evaluation of modular polynomials

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, optimization

A polynomial is defined such that all of its coefficients given are less than a prime number P. I wish to evaluate the polynomial at a point mod P. A simple approach would be;

```
 int sum=arr[n],j=n-1;//sum is the polynomial value mod P at that point and arr[] is the coefficient array and k is the point at which polynomial is to be evaluated
    while(j>=0)
    {
       sum = ((sum*k)%P + arr[j])%P;
       j--;
    }
```

But does any property exist regarding such polynomials such that the above approach could be optimized further (lesser time complexity)?

Comment: There are O(n) coefficients that cannot be known ahead of time, so I can't imagine you're going to do better than O(n) operations to evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: @GuyGreer but I was wondering whether it was possible to reduce the number of operations. Above I had to use addition N times and multiplication N times, also the modular operations....

Comment: You can do some quick checks before doing each remainder operation, since those can be expensive.

Comment: You can remove the first '%P' from the expression (you may have to choose long long int instead of int in that case).

Comment: Shouldn't polynomial have a power calculation somewhere? Update: Ah, got it.

Comment: So which is it? Are you looking for improved asymptotic complexity, as stated in question, or just for minimizing instruction count, as you later claim in a comment?  Or maybe something else, such as minimizing observed running time?

Comment: FYI, probably part of live competitive coding contest: https://www.codechef.com/JULY16/problems/POLYEVAL

Comment: A bit of topic: You can make your code less vulnerable to integer overflow by calculating `r = k % P` before the loop and then do `sum = (sum*r + arr[j])%P;` In this way you don't have to care about large values of `k`. You only need to make sure that `(P-1)*(P-1) + P` doesn't overflow.